# What doesn the url get format pattern like 1_*1 means

Tags: http, url, linkedin-api

What does the following patterm means in the URL, these pattern seen on variety of url like Linkedin

Enpv_301654428_***1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1**

is this sparse Matrix representation ?

For example

```
https://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=5010991&goback=%2Enpv_301654428_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1&trk=prof-groups-membership-name
```

I know it's the value passed to the parameter `goback`, but what's the point to use this kind of strange looking values?

Comment: It is a variable value.  The variable name is `goback`.  The exact nature of what these values imply is down to the implementation, but the name suggests it's a means of identifying where to return the user to when they click a back link.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check this 
[this](http://www.quora.com/Why-do-LinkedIn-URLs-look-so-messy) link!

It's basically a method to allow the system remember steps to go forward\backward in the navigation.

EDIT:

[image]

When you perform a search on LinkedIn, there are a number of facets on the left hand side of the search results page that you can use to refine your search, like company and location. When you click on a search result, it turns all of those facets into the *1_s and *2_s that you see in the URL. Those are used to construct the "Go back to Search Results" link, which will restore the facets you had selected.

This [stackoverflow](http://shttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745690/linkedin-url-function) previous question may also help you.

Comment: Please provide some more information instead of only posting a link, so that your answer stays relevant to future readers even if the link breaks or changes.